# Do not lose focus of a div even if clicked outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 4 `div`s with `tabindex`. When I click on a `div` it get focused and change border color.

After selecting a `div` if I click outside I lose focus of selected `div` (as expected).

Is there a way, I loose focus only if I click on other `div` and not outside of `div`.

```js
function onCLickHandle(){
 var element = document.getElementById("details");
  element.classList.remove("d-none");
}

function Validate() 
{
    var val = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
    
    if (!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) 
    {
        alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

```css
h4{
  font-size: 32px;
}

.box {
  border:  1px solid #BBBBBB;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 175px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #BBBBB;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.box div:focus{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input{
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 47px;
  min-height: 47px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div>
<h4>
Request a Service
</h4>
<h6 class="mt-5">
Select a service
</h6>
  <div class="row mx-1">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12  box" onClick="onCLickHandle()" tabindex="1">
     Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box  mb-3" onClick="onCLickHandle()" tabindex="2">
    Box 2 
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box" onClick="onCLickHandle()" tabindex="3">
    Box 3    
</div>
 <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box" onClick="onCLickHandle()" tabindex="4">
    Box 4    
</div>
 
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="details"  class="d-none">
   <h6 class="px-1">
  Your Details
  </h6>
  <div class="row px-4">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-12 px-2">
  <div>Full Name</div>
  <input type="text" id="fullname"/>
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-12 px-2">
  <div>Email</div>
  <input id="email" type="email" />
  </div>
    
 <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto my-auto">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn" onClick="Validate()"/>
  </div>
  
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Not a reactjs issue. Instead of binding the click even to the document, bind it to each div.

Comment: @DeanJames Binding to `document` is fine (and preferred to setting up multiple event handlers). All that needs to happen is a check to see if the `event.target` is one of the desired `div` elements.

Comment: @DeanJames please check the link. There is only html and css.https://codepen.io/sanjeet2411/pen/yLJWeyY

Comment: Yes, you tagged this as a reactjs. Also at the very least, I'd bind to a wrapping elelemt responsible for the click rather than the document. As an app grows, the document shouldn't be responsible for determining what to do on clicks from a variety of elements.

Answer (score 0):

See the HTML and JavaScript comments below for description of code:

```js
let active = document.activeElement;

// Do your event binding in JavaScript, not with inline event attributes
// in the HTML.
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  // Cancel the document click behavior
  
  // Check to see if the click originated at one of your boxes
  if(event.target.classList.contains("box")){
    // Remove the focus from all the divs
    document.querySelectorAll(".box div").forEach(function(box){
      box.blur();  // Remove the focus
    });
    event.target.focus();   // Set the focus on the clicked box
    active = event.target;  // Make the clicked box the "flagged" active element
  }
  active.focus();  // Set the focus on the flagged element
});

// Get references for elements you'll need over and over just once
const fullName = document.getElementById('fullname');

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  if (!fullName.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)){
    alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
  }
});
```

```css
h4 { font-size: 32px; }

.box {
  border:  1px solid #BBBBBB;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 175px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #BBBBB;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.box div:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input{
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 47px;
  min-height: 47px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h4>Request a Service</h4>
    <h6 class="mt-5">Select a service</h6>
    <div class="row mx-1">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box" tabindex="1">Box 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box  mb-3" tabindex="2">Box 2</div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box" tabindex="3">Box 3</div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-12 box" tabindex="4">Box 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="details" class="d-none">
   <h6 class="px-1">Your Details</h6>
    <div class="row px-4">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-12 px-2">
        <div>Full Name</div>
        <input type="text" id="fullname"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-12 px-2">
        <div>Email</div>
        <input id="email" type="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto my-auto">
        <!-- You can't have a submit button without a <form> and if you are
             using a <form>, then it's the submit event of the form that should
             be handled, not the submit event of the submit button. If you 
             just use a regular button (as shown below), then you handle the
             click event of the button. -->
        <input type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```